# Property 'id' is being taken from a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, macos

i'm new with Laravel and MacOS and I'm using Laravel 7. While trying to develop a News Website, I created a button to 'edit' the news the user creates, but this error appears:

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /Users/rodri6uez/Documents/LARAVEL/noticias/resources/views/noticias/edit.blade.php)

The error points to the next line of code:

```
<form action="{{ route('noticias.update',['id' => $noticia ?? '' ->id]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This is the code for the controller that affects the edit function:

```
public function edit($noticia)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $noticia = DB::table('noticias')
        ->join('categorias', 'noticias.categorias_id', '=', 'categorias.id')
        ->join('users', 'noticias.users_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('noticias.users_id', $user->id)
        ->where('noticias.id', $noticia)
        ->select('noticias.*', 'categorias.descripcion as categoriadescripcion', 'users.name as usuario')
        ->first();

    $categorias = categoria::where('estatus', 1)
        ->orderBy('descripcion', 'desc')
        ->get();
    return view('noticias.edit', ['id' => $noticia, 'categorias' => $categorias]);
}
```

I do not know if this is enough information, if not just let me know to post it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You passed `$noticia` to the view and called it `id` so in the view you should use `route('noticias.update',['id' => $id->id])` though I would consider renaming the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

In `$noticia` you are getting object values. So follow below code -

```
<form action="{{ route('noticias.update',['id' => $noticia ?? '' $noticia->id]) }}"
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Hope this will help you. Happy codding.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming! I did that and now it's telling me this: syntax error, unexpected '$noticia' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']'

Comment: Try ```['id' => $noticia->id]```.

Comment: says this: $noticia is undefined

Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $noticia }} with {{ $noticia ?? '' }}

Comment: Can you dd($noticia)?

Comment: Still not working. I do not know what is going on but, thanks a lot man I really appreciate it!

Comment: Are you getting any data in ```$noticia```?

Comment: You have passed a data in ```id``` so try ```@dd($id)```. I believe that you will get data. If you got so then try ```<form action="{{ route('noticias.update',['id' => $id->id]) }}"
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
<form action="{{ route('noticias.update',['id' => $noticia ?? '' $noticia->id]) }}"
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```